# How to calculate this definite integral: $\int_{0}^{2} x^x dx$???

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

According to **Sophomore's Dream**:

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^x dx = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n)^{-n}$$

Now, I want to find $\int_{0}^{2} x^x dx$. Because they are quite similar, is there any way I could use **Sophomore's Dream** to help me find an answer for the integral in question? Or do I have to use other methods? Either way, what would I do?

Comment: you can also [go back to the proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) and apply the change of variable $x = 2 e^{y}$ in the obtained $\int_0^2 x^n (\log x)^n dx$ terms

Comment: According to https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function $$\int_0^2 x^x dx=Sphd(1\:;\:2)$$ and from numerical calculus $\simeq 2.83388$ Infinite series are given in the above paper.